# How to find public class name in java program using php?

Tags: php, laravel

I am building an online compiler for java. The problem is i want to detect the public class name in java program using php.
e.g:-

```
public class MyProgram{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Hello world");
  }
}
```

Let's suppose we have the above code from a text editor and send to the server. Then on the server i want to detect `MyProgram` from value of that editor using php, so that i could create a file with that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't claim to be a regular expressions expert, but the following helper function seems like it may do the trick. You could always modify it more as needed.

```php
function get_java_class($string) {
    // regex
    $re = '/\s+class\s+(\D[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s*{/m';
    // find matches
    preg_match_all($re, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
    // return class name or null
    return $matches[0][1] ?? null;
}
```

```php
$class_name = get_java_class($string);
```

Check it out here:
https://regex101.com/r/owmRaB/2

*Please note that the null coalescing operator `??` requires PHP 7+.*

Comment: Wow, that was fast!  Glad to help.

Comment: @musawer if the answer helped, please mark it as correct.